# How to calculate the difference between max/min dates on non static pivot tables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a pivot table like this

```
A | 01/01/2001 | 01/02/2001
A | 01/01/2001 | 01/02/2008
B | 01/01/1994 | 01/11/2015
B | 01/01/2006 | 01/02/2014
B | 11/01/2016 | 19/07/2018
C | 01/03/2006 | 21/02/2014
C | 01/06/2016 | 01/05/2017
...
```

I want to create a pivot table that displays the difference in months so either this:

```
A | 01/01/2001 | 01/02/2001 | 1
A | 01/01/2001 | 01/02/2008 | 85
etc...
```

or just the months:

```
A | 1
A | 85
etc...
```

Of course I could just use `=DATEDIF(date1,date2,"M")` which would work but I also want to add a slicer so I can filter `A, B, C, ...` this means the number of rows is not fixed and so I cannot just add that formula.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate field inside the Pivot Table itself, and then you'll be able to use the slicers

Navigation:

**PivotTable Tools>>Analyze>>Field Items & Sets>>Calculate Field**

And then paste your datedif formula

```
=DATEDIF(Date1,Date2,"M")
```

Hope it helps!